# MySQL set wait_timeout for specific user

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Is it possible to set the global `wait_timeout` for a particular user?

For example user: `jack` has a timeout of 60s and `root` user has unlimited timeout?

`SET SESSION wait_timeout = X;` only affects the current session.

`SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = X;` affects everything.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how variables work. [Variables are either scoped to a session or to the global variable store.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html) Session variables can be defined through command-line parameters.

Now, it looks like you might have the option of setting the global timeout to `jack`'s timeout, and then let `SUPER` users have the ability to override on a session basis.